# Android long to time

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Я хочу вывести изменение текста `timer`

```
countDownTimer = object : CountDownTimer(premiumInfo.overTime.time - System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000) {

    override fun onTick(p0: Long) {
        Log.d("Timer", p0.toString())
        val format = SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss")
        val timeString = format.format(Date(p0).time)
        Log.d("Timer String", timeString)
        switch_premium.text = "Премиум [$timeString]"
    }

    override fun onFinish() {
        Log.d("Finish", "true")
        switch_premium.text = "Премиум"
        context?.let {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Обновление данных", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        getProfile()
    }
}.start()
```

Но полученное время на 3 часа больше (думаю это часовой пояс). Мне же нужно без `timeZone`. Как поправить?

**Log**

```
2020-05-13 19:06:19.651 18783-18783/com.app.peshkariki D/Timer: 53349
2020-05-13 19:06:19.656 18783-18783/com.app.peshkariki D/Timer String: 03:00:53
2020-05-13 19:06:20.654 18783-18783/com.app.peshkariki D/Timer: 52346
2020-05-13 19:06:20.659 18783-18783/com.app.peshkariki D/Timer String: 03:00:52
2020-05-13 19:06:21.059 19322-19336/? I/cebook.service: ProcessProfilingInfo new_methods=0 is saved saved_to_disk=0 resolve_classes_delay=8000
2020-05-13 19:06:21.656 18783-18783/com.app.peshkariki D/Timer: 51344
2020-05-13 19:06:21.663 18783-18783/com.app.peshkariki D/Timer String: 03:00:51
2020-05-13 19:06:22.658 18783-18783/com.app.peshkariki D/Timer: 50342
2020-05-13 19:06:22.662 18783-18783/com.app.peshkariki D/Timer String: 03:00:50
```

**Ладно, давайте начнем сначала, может я не туда пошел и все осложнил.**

С сервера приходит дата в формате

```
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
```

Так как Gson не знает как разбираться (а в будущем Room как хранить), приходится писать TypeConverter

```
class GsonUTCDateAdapter : JsonSerializer<Date?>, JsonDeserializer<Date?> {
    private val dateFormat: DateFormat

    @Synchronized
    override fun serialize(date: Date?, type: Type?, context: JsonSerializationContext?): JsonElement {
        return JsonPrimitive(dateFormat.format(date))
    }

    @Synchronized
    override fun deserialize(jsonElement: JsonElement, type: Type?, jsonDeserializationContext: JsonDeserializationContext?): Date {
        return try {
            dateFormat.parse(jsonElement.asString)
        } catch (e: ParseException) {
            throw JsonParseException(e)
        }
    }

    init {
        dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault()) //This is the key line which converts the date to UTC which cannot be accessed with the default serializer
    }
}
```

Таким образом мы приводим к типу `Date`

```
data class PremiumInfo(
        @SerializedName("is_active") var isActive: Int,
        @SerializedName("premium_description") var description: String,
        @SerializedName("premium_over_time") var overTime: Date,
        @SerializedName("premium_over_timeleft_text") var overTimeLeftText: String
)
```

Так как CountDownTimer принимает на вход 2 параметра Long (от какого времени, и с какой периодичностью)

Что такое длительность времени? Это разница 2 дат, поэтому я использую пришедшую Date и текущее системное время (так как непонятно в какой timeZone пришло с сервера), произвожу разницу и это время начала (длительность премиум аккаунта) собственно в формате Long.

Каждый Tick время уменьшается на 2 параметр. Теперь осталось Long превратить в Date и получить Time, но при переводе из Long в Date откуда - то взялась разница в 3 часа. Откуда он взялся, ну наверно в SimpleDateFormat. Я посмотрел, там есть есть метод setZone, но зачем мне для продолжительности зона, так ведь?
а setZone установить в null нельзя.

Поэтому я и спросил решение. Возможно можно где - то проще сделать, например Joda - Time (там и Period и Duration) использовать, но эта библиотека избытачна , а вес приложения увеличит, поэтому я и спросил, можно как-то по другому сделать стандартными пакетами Java и Kotlin такую простейшую операцию

Comment: а почему нужно без timezone? насколько я знаю в simpledataformat можно timezone вставить и должно быть по логике нормально

Comment: @Andrew мне нужно не само время, а сколько осталось, т.е продолжнительность

Comment: @Andrew можно конечно и самому разделить сначала на часы, минуты и секунды а потом собрать в String. Но неужели ни один пакет не умеет это делать?

Comment: Joda time не предлагать, слишком большая библиотека

Comment: https://github.com/thunder413/DateTimeUtils - вот есть либа, но вообще я бы советовал использовать встроенные варианты решения

Comment: @Andrew ясно, тогда лучше сам метод напишу =)

Comment: Вы что-то где-то переусложняете. Продолжительность есть понятие независимое от часового пояса. Правильно выставляйте `premiumInfo.overTime` и все будет работать.

Comment: Вот вам и ответ. Время, что вам приходит с сервера `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`, это время где? В какой точке мира? Как только вы будете знать часовой пояс, все ваши проблемы исчезнут.

Comment: 2020-05-13 16:05:55 в Токио и в Париже, согласитесь не в один момент времени настает. 7 часов разницы!

Answer (score 3):

Это не ответ, а скорее разъяснение где в подобных задачах с датами кроются подводные камни.

Компьютерам по сути плевать на часовые пояса, их придумали люди, чтобы с одной стороны себе жизнь облегчить, с другой стороны усложнить, занимаясь расчетами.

С точки зрения ОС Линукс, абсолютное время это `System.currentTimeMillis()`

> the difference, measured in milliseconds, between the current time and midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC.

Т.е. у компьютеров свои боги и это просто сколько миллисекунд прошло с полуночи 1-го января 1970 по Гринвичу.

Вот тут и кроется подводный камень, в последнем слове **по Гринвичу**. В полночь по Гринвичу в Берлине уже 2:00, а в Москве и того 3:00.
Поэтому когда получаете откуда-то дату и время в "человеческом" формате (текстовом), необходимо всегда при переводе в "компьютерный" формат (бинарный) учитывать "человеческий" часовой пояс.
Иначе всегда (кроме, конечно случаев что вы в зоне UTC+0) будут возникать расхождения, пытаясь их "как-то" решить, будете по факту просто костылить свой код. Костыли как правило перестают работать, когда к простому "сдвигу" во времени еще добавится переход в другую дату.

Поверьте, все это уже решили до вас. Просто пользуйтесь, выставляйте часовой пояс у даты корректно и все будет работать как надо.

Уточнение. Понятие по Гринвичу устарело :) Правильно

> UTC – Всемирное координированное время

Comment: добавил описание задачи

Comment: @danilshik, вам никакая библиотека не сможет заменить отсутствующие данные о часовом поясе. Просите сервер отправлять дату в стандартном формате (Zulu раньше назывался).
https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter#ISO_INSTANT

Comment: И Gson и Room только спасибо скажут.

Comment: Тут есть образцы кода для любого API, стандартно Android этот формат понимает с API26. https://medium.com/@kosta.palash/converting-date-time-considering-time-zone-android-b389ff9d5c49